# Unable use functions on templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class called **Variables** which just adds variables together as I want:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class Variables
{
public:
    Variables operator+( Variables& );
    void set(Type);
    void print() const;
    Variables();
private:
    Type item;
};

int main( )
{
    Variables<int> V1, V2, Vi;
    Variables<string> V3, V4, Vs;
    Variables<char> V5, V6, Vc;
    Variables<bool> V7, V8, Vb;

    V1.set(4);      V1.print();
    V2.set(2);      V2.print();

    V3.set("Hello");   V3.print();
    V4.set("Friends!");  V4.print();

    V5.set('s');    V5.print();
    V6.set('m');    V6.print();

    V7.set(true);       V7.print();
    V8.set(false);      V8.print();

    cout << "---------------------" << endl;

    Vi = V1 + V2;   Vi.print();
    Vs = V3 + V4;   Vs.print();
    Vc = V5 + V6;   Vc.print();
    Vb = V7 + V8;   Vb.print();

    return 0;
}

template <class Type>
Variables<Type> Variables<Type>::operator+( Variables& x )
{
    Variables<Type> t;

    if(typeid(item) == typeid(int) || typeid(item) == typeid(double))
        t.item = item + x.item;
    else if(typeid(item) == typeid(string))
        t.item = item + " " + x.item; // Line 55
    else if(typeid(item) == typeid(bool))
        t.item = (item || x.item); // Line 57
    else if(typeid(item) == typeid(char))
        t.item = 'Z';

    return t;
}

template <class Type>
void Variables<Type>::set(Type x)
{
    item = x;
}

template <class Type>
void Variables<Type>::print() const
{
    cout << "The value of the variable is: " << item << endl;
}

template <class Type>
Variables<Type>::Variables()
{

}
```

I'm trying to use *typeid()* in order to get the type of the variable and do what I want. But this code doesn't seem to work as of lines 55 and 57.

```
Line 55: The operator + can't be used with string and int
Line 57: The operator || can't be used with strings
```

Although, I don't want to use them like this, I'm trying to get the type of variables so I can do what I want, but this way doesn't seem to work. How can I fix this?

Comment: Using something like `typeid(item) == typeid(int)` is often a sign of bad design. As for the implementation I would suggest you do some research about *specialization*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++17, use `std::is_same` in a `if constexpr`:

```
template <class Type>
Variables<Type> Variables<Type>::operator+( Variables& x )
{
    Variables<Type> t;

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type,int> || std::is_same_v<Type,double>)
        t.item = item + x.item;
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Type,double>)
        t.item = item + " " + x.item; // Line 55
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Type,bool>)
        t.item = (item || x.item); // Line 57
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<Type,char>)
        t.item = 'Z';

    return t;
}
```

Alternatively, specialize for the different types. Or use a non-templated overloaded function so you can write:

```
template <class Type>
Variables<Type> Variables<Type>::operator+( Variables& x )
{
    return foo(item,x.item);
}
```